# I am getting blank space in between two paragraphs due to "\nobibliography"

Tags: spacing

I am getting 5 or 6 lines worth of blank space between two paragraphs in my CV. This blank space is due to the reference lines:

```
\nobibliography{publications.bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

If I remove these two lines the space vanish, but also I cannot use the reference. What is a good way to keep my reference and also not have this line? The look of my document is as below:

[image]

---

A minimal short file that exhibits this issue is shown below. I have only compiled this on overleaf, I am unsure about other places, or if even that matters or not.

The .tex file contains the following lines:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkbordercolor = {white},
    urlcolor = blue,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[left=0.4in,top=0.4in,right=0.4in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins

\name{First Name Last Name} % Your name
 % Your address


\address{Address}

\address{
}

% \address{(618)~$\cdot$~525~$\cdot$~0387 \\ riyasatohib@iut-dhaka.edu}  
\address{( \\ \href{}{Email:email}}  


%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  BIBLIOGRAPHY PACKAGE DELETE THESE IF COMPILE ERROR ------------
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{bibentry}
% \usepackage{cite}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother

\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand\publication[1]{%
    \smallskip\par\hangpara{1.5em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip
}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf University} \hfill {} \\ 
\end{rSection}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------------------------Work and Industrial Experience
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{BAU}{Oct 2015 - Nov 2015}{Industrial Trainee}{}
\item Learned the basic operation.
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------------------ Leadership
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{rSection}{Leadership}

\begin{rSubsection}{ Volunter etc}{July 2016 - Oct 2016}{Instructor}{Location}
\item Developed and instructed a two month-long programming and signal processing course.
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{Chief Organizer}{September 2016}{Competition}

\item Organized and directed the coding contest 2016 - a large scale EE event.
\item Set the contest problems and judged the event.
\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------------------ PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\nobibliography{publications.bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 

\begin{rSection}{Publications}

\begin{rSubsection}{Peer-Reviewed Publications}{}{}{}
\publication{Author1t2018}

\publication{Author22018}

\publication{Author32018}

\end{rSubsection}


\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

---

The .cls file is here:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[9pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
     \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\smallskip % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

---

And Finally, the Bibliography .bib file is here:

```
@article{Author1t2018,
  title={Title of the paper in Conference},
  author={FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName },
  journal={IEEE ICEECS 2018, Conference.},
  year={2018}}

@article{Author22018,
  title={Title of the paper in Conference},
  author={ FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName},
  journal={IEEE R10HTC 2017, Conference},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}}

 @article{Author32018,
  title={Metal nanoparticle enhanced light absorption in GaAs thin-film solar cell.},
  author={FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName and FirstName LastName},
  volume={3},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Pearson Education}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We need a bit more information to answer the question. The `rSection` environment is not standard, so you are using a custom class or package. This can influence the vertical spacing. Please post a small complete document, starting with `\documentclass`, then packages (if any), `\begin{document}`, then the first subsection, the bibliography, the second subsection, `\end{document}`. Make sure it can be compiled and it shows the issue that you ask about. This will make it much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi! I know it's late, but I have a very concise version of the problem in this overleaf project: https://www.overleaf.com/1715488292dcqssymnhfct

Using more references causes more space before the reference section (it seems like!). So, if I just leave the first reference only and comment out the rest, there won't be any space. Please take a look if you can. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, we like questions on this site to be as self-contained as possible, without references to external sources. There are several reasons for that: first a external resource can go down or change, at which point the question is no longer useful for future visitors, second it is much easier to check for other visitors if your question is related to their own problem and/or interest if the code is in the question itself, and third the person asking the question should make it as easy as possible for potential answerers to understand the question,

Comment: and going to an external site which requires an account does not help with that. So if you can post the code of your example Overleaf project here in the question (by pressing the `edit` button) then the question will become more useful and easier to answer.

Comment: Hello @Marijn I have edited the question and did my best to post the whole compilable file here. Please, do let me know if it doesnt work or something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, this is much better. I don't have time to fully investigate the issue now, but I saw a few small things. At the end of `resume.cls` on line 129 there is a `}` missing after `\smallskip`. This causes an error, maybe you compile in batchmode, which ignores errors? That may cause the wrong output. Also, in the `.tex` file there are duplicate entries for `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{geometry}`, which cause `option clash` errors, and a separate error for the first `hypersetup` line complaining about `linkbordercolor = {white}`.

Comment: A quick fix for these issues gives a further `Lonely \item` error in the `\publication` commands. So currently the code you provided does not reproduce the behavior. Maybe you can try to fix that, making sure that the code you posted here results in the issue that you have? Make a new Overleaf project, upload the three files, make sure compilation is done with halt on error, and fix any issues that come up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Importing `natbib` before `bibentry` fixed the error for me on overleaf.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue!!

Comment: I'm getting tired of what feels like random fixes for LaTeX problems.

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me. Instead it added several equals signs to the start of the document, which is perplexing, and altered the margins. Using with modernCV.